# Linker error on referenced exe project in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

I created a Google Test project to test an executable project.

I added a reference to the executable project.

I'm getting a linker error: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl Utilities::CopyFileToRemoteLocation(...`

I'm seeing from one source that the reason this is happening is because it's an exe project and it needs to be a dll.
[Google Test: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol with Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332280/google-test-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-with-visual-studio-2013)

The thing is, I need it to be an executable.

Will I have to separate the logic into a dll?  Will I be able to statically link that dll if I do?  We need to have a single-file executable for delivery.

Opinions on best course of action?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements the only option is to separate all of the code you intend to test into a *static library*. This will allow you to maintain a single executable file with no additional runtime dependencies and create a separate application for testing.